# ZIndex doesn't work with ContentControl?

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

I am trying to create a floor layout by overlaying controls using a Canvas that contains shape controls (e.g. Rectangle, Ellipse).  One portion of the layout is a rectangle that contains three circles.  Since the circles are the same size/color, I created a resource for them.  I am attempting to place the circles on top of the rectangle.  My problem is that only the last circle appears.  I tried to use Panel.Zindex, but it does not work.

After some experimentation, I have found that the problem seems to be that ZIndex does not work with a ContentControl.  If I replace the ContentControl with an Ellipse, then it works fine.  I have tried alternate methods but the problem just seems to be that the ContentControl does not obey ZIndex.  I have tried using a border around the Canvas.  I have tried using no rectangle and filling the Canvas background.

Below is my XAML with examples of what works and what doesn't.

```html
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Ellipse x:Key="MyCircle" Fill="Black" Width="1.5" Height="1.5"/>

        <!--uses resource, but only shows last ellipse-->
        <Canvas x:Key="LastEllipseOnly">
            <Rectangle Fill="DarkGray" Width="6" Height="2.5" />

            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyCircle}" Canvas.Left="0.5" Canvas.Top="0.5"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyCircle}" Canvas.Left="2.25" Canvas.Top="0.5"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyCircle}" Canvas.Left="4.0" Canvas.Top="0.5"/>
        </Canvas>

        <!--this works, but it does not use the resource-->
        <Canvas x:Key="Working"  Width="6" Height="2.5">
                <Rectangle Fill="DarkGray" Width="6" Height="2.5"/>

                <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="1.5" Height="1.5" Canvas.Left="0.5" Canvas.Top="0.5"/>
                <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="1.5" Height="1.5" Canvas.Left="2.25" Canvas.Top="0.5"/>
                <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="1.5" Height="1.5" Canvas.Left="4.0" Canvas.Top="0.5"/>
        </Canvas>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Viewbox>
    <Canvas Height="50" Width="50">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource LastEllipseOnly}" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>

        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Working}" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="40"/>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: your ellipes is above your rectangle.. where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the ZIndex. The problem is that there is only one instance of the Ellipse resource, which is repeatedly used as Content of multiple ContentControls. However, an element can only be added once to the visual tree.

You can get around this limitation by telling WPF that it should create multiple instance of the resource, by setting the `x:Shared` attribute to false:

```
<Ellipse x:Key="MyCircle" ... x:Shared="False"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Clemens!  That was the problem.  Strangely, this issue doesn't affect the designer, where it shows all my ellipses.

Comment: I've also noticed that. Maybe in designer resources are always created unshared.